# WPF/Prism/MVVM Button/DelegateCommand binding with user-defined button disable logic?

Tags: wpf, prism

What I want to do is bind a SaveCommand DelegateCommand to a button, but instead of having the CanExecute() == false disable the button, I'd prefer the button be clickable but just run field validation and display a message box if fields are invalid.

I'm using MVVM and would like to achieve this without doing something hackity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just have your Execute method of the command do as you state and only use the CanExecute to enable/disable the button? If you don't need to ever disable the button, then only use the Execute portion...

Comment: Yeah, I was messing around with it and essentially did that. I had so many other things to consider in the code the simple solution just didn't jump out at me.  I got FocusVMLib and if the fields aren't valid I used the IMoveFocus RaiseMoveFocus(propertName) to move focus to the first invalid field instead of executing so basically I don't define a CanExecute.